# Coprocesses and two-way pipes in awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand the difference between `command | getline var` and `command |& getline var`.  Which one should I normally use?  Have been reading about coprocesses and two-way pipes, but need some explanation because things are becoming quite confusing.

In actual practical terms, I am using

```
kmd=sprintf("%s%d\n", "tput bold; tput setaf ", knum)
tseq[knam] = ( (kmd | getline outp) > 0 ? outp : "<" knam ">" )
close(kmd)
```

What is the coprocess here ?  Is it in the use of tput.  I would think there in just a one-way pipeline communication in the code.  What would be the benefit of using `kmd |& getline outp`, and should I use the latter instead?

Comment: Read [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fCoprocess.html) for differences and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html) for more details about it. As mentioned co-processes is GNU awk specifc feature.

Comment: The problem is that I have read all that, but did not find the discussions clear enough.

Comment: see also [Using getline into a Variable from a Coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess.html) vs [Using getline into a Variable from a Pipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html) for details of each. And that depends on your need which one do you need. could you [edit] your question and clarify what is your need and where do you stuck on choosing which one you should pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should continue using simple "|". if your task is: give some data to external tool and use the result provided by that tool. Then a simple one-directional pipe is enough.

The bi-directional pipe is needed only if:

- you want to keep the same instance of the external tool in memory for the whole life-time of your own process.
- the data, you are sending to the external tool, is split logically into packets
- you need to receive result of processing one packet before sending the next one
- you need to adjust next packet of data according of the result of the previous packet(s)

If one of these four question is "no" - you do not need bi-directional pipes.

It is very difficult to invent a real-life example, where this bi-directional pipe can be useful. It, probably, was invented to be used with some database query tools or web-applications. But in overwhelming majority of cases, if there is a need to work with some kind of a server, these tasks are usually solved in a languages like `perl`, `python` or even shell. `awk` is usually reserved for text-processing only.

Here is a not-realistic, but technically correct example:

```
#!/bin/gawk
BEGIN {
  tool="bc"

  print "2+3" |& tool
  tool |& getline res

  if (res>4)
     print "5+6" |& tool
  else 
     print "10+45" |& tool
  tool |& getline res

  close(tool, "to")

  print res
}
```

As you can see here, the first print sends a "query" into external tool (simple calculator `bc` in that case). Then upon result of the first query, it sends another query, and finally prints the result. It is the same instance of the tool which process both queries. It is open from the first `print "2+3" |& command` to the special statement `close(command, "to")`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no coprocess in the code in your question - what you have is simply spawning a subshell to call `tput` and then reading that subshells output with `getline`.

Regarding `What would be the benefit of using kmd |& getline outp, and should I use the latter instead?` - not only wouldn't there be any benefit but that'd be only half of the syntax, you'd need something like (plus error-handling):

```
print knum |& kcmd
kcmd |& getline outp
close(kcmd)
```

but that'd only begin to make sense if `kcmd` contains a command that continuously read stdin and produced stdout and even if it did there would be no benefit for what you're trying to do and it'd make your code unnecessarily gawk-specific.

Here's an example of when you would find a coprocess useful, sorting an incoming stream of numbers by piping to `sort` and then doing something with those numbers (e.g. dividing them by the number of lines read or anything else at all) before printing them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    cmd = "sort -rn"
}
{ print |& cmd }
END {
    close(cmd, "to")
    while ( (cmd |& getline line) > 0 ) {
        print line, line / NR
    }
    close(cmd)
}
```

```
$ seq 5 | awk -f tst.awk
5 1
4 0.8
3 0.6
2 0.4
1 0.2
```

Basically, if you ever find yourself writing an awk script where you need to write to a temporary file, call some external command on that file, and then read the output of that command back into your script - THAT is when you should consider using coprocesses instead as it can remove the need for that temporary file to be created.

Please get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and read the sections related to Two-Way Communications with Another Process for more information.

Comment: Meaning that I can stay with `tseq[knam] = ( (kmd | getline outp) > 0 ? outp : "<" knam ">" )`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've shown you to do in every answer I've posted. The only reason coprocesses have come up is because you keep writing code to use them and so I keep telling you not to do that.